# Как передавать любые файлы, используя протокол TCP\IP и python serversocket

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, tcp-ip

Всех приветствую!

Возникла необходимость разработать скрипт на python (framework socketserver), который при посредством протокола TCP\IP сможет передавать любые файлы от клиентов на сервер.

Обычными сообщениями клиент-сервер обменивается. С этим проблем нет.

Вопрос заключается в правильной передачи файлов. Ниже приведены исходные коды скриптов сервера и клиента.

**serverforever.py**

```
import socketserver

class ThreadingTCPserver(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

class EchoTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

def handle(self):
    data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    print('Address: {}'.format(self.client_address[0]))
    self.request.sendall(data)

    f = open('take_file_pulse.txt', 'wb')
    f.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadingTCPserver(('', 8888), EchoTCPHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

**client.py**

```
from socket import * 
import os 

tcpClientSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8888

ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUFSIZE = 1024

tcpClientSock.connect(ADDR)

f = open('pulse.txt', 'rb')
f_data = f.read(BUFSIZE)
f.close()

tcpClientSock.send(f_data)
```

Такое прокатывает с обычными текстовыми файлами, картинкой. При попытке переслать видео - создается файл с определенным названием и расширением размером в 1 КВ и всё. На стороне клиентского скрипта в консоли выводит сообщение, что сервер разорвал соединение. Была попытка считывать через **While**, но это ничего не поменяло.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать передачу абсолютно любых файлов данным способом?
Заранее благодарен!